# how to ignore / skip invalid data row in LOAD DATA INFILE while loading data from csv.

Tags: mysql, load-data-infile

I am trying to load data from CSV file, In few date field columns data in CSV is invalid. But when i run LOAD DATA INFILE statement, it inserts NULL value in those column. how can I skip entire row which has invalid data ?

Comment: What do you mean - invalid? If there were invalid data, then LOAD DATA INFILE would stop working; but in your case it continues working, just inserts NULLs. Show the example.

Comment: Yes it inserts NULL but instead of NULL, I want to skip that record insertion which has invalid (data which does not match data type in database e.g. string data inserting in to datetime field).

Answer (score 2):

You cant skip those rows, if you are using load in file function. Do one thing, initially load all data into a temporary table and then from that table pull only valid rows to your staging table. once you will insert all rows into staging table delete that temporary table!

Comment: Do u mean using IGNORE LINES ? Actually wanted to ask, is there anyway to do it without specifying line numbers. Is there anything in MySQL, LOAD DATA INFILE which can recognize invalid rows and skip those ?

Comment: No i am not saying about ignore line. Since rows may not be fixed, so you can't use ignore lines. No there is such method in load infile function which will serve your purpose. better to use what i suggested in my answer.

Comment: Thanks, but as at the time of loading data in temp table, it will insert NULL values, it will not be possible to recognize which NULL values are due to invalid data and which are not ?

Comment: which type of invalid data you are talking about? During the process of INFILE insertion you can check or validate any thing.but once you will insert the data into temp table then you can analyze which one is invalid and which one is not.

Answer (score 0):

when you are loading data through csv files. date should be in yyyy-mm--dd HH:MM:SS format. otherwise it inserts NULL values..in csv file select the date whole column and right click on it. click on format cell and select 'date' column in right side and also select 'custom'. then you can see format 'yyyy/mm/dd' change it to 'yyyy-mm--dd HH:MM:SS' . do the same for all date columns using format painter at the top left of csv file. this should solve you problem i guess.

Answer (score 0):

You can skip invalid null dates by using a `NOT NULL` on the date column when creating the table.